# TransactionScope doesn't rollback in per-test TearDown for integration testing using NUnit and TestServer

Tags: c#, transactions, nunit, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.0

### Scenario

I have an API on ASP.NET Core 2.0 that integrates with MS SQL database using EF Core. Now I am trying to setup integration/api tests for it using NUnit and `TestServer`. The issue is that I need to configure every test to be 'isolated' so basically it should clean up (rollback) DB after self. I cannot use compensation transactions to achieve the desired result due to the complexity of DB (lots of legacy stuff to account for, e.g. triggers etc).

### SUT API Setup

Here is an example of API I am trying to test:

```cs
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string dataName1, string dataName2)
{
    using (var scope = CreateScope())
    {
        await _service.DoWork(dataName1);
        await _service.DoWork(dataName2);
        scope.Complete();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

The `DoWork()` method basically looks up an entity given passed parameter and increments its another property. Then simply calls `SaveChanges()`.
The `CreateScope()` is here a helper method that returns an instance of `TransactionScope`:

```cs
return new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead },
    TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled
);
```

### Integration Test Setup

```cs
[TestFixture]
[SingleThreaded]
[NonParallelizable]
public class TestTest
{
    private TransactionScope _scope;

    [Test]
    public async Task Test11()
    {
        _scope = CreateScope();
        var result = await Client.GetAsync("api/values?dataName1=Name1&dataName2=Name2");
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

        _scope.Dispose();
        _scope = null;
    }
}
```

Here the `Client` is an instance of `HttpClient` created by utilizing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer` and `CreateScope()` method is actually the same as in the API.
This simple case works fine - the changes made by my SUT API are rollbacked successfully by calling `_scope.Dispose()` and DB returns to its 'clean' state.

### Problem

Now I want to move the logic related to create/rollback of scope outside of my test method and put it in SetUp/TearDown so all my tests are automatically handled.

```cs
[SetUp]
public async Task SetupTest()
{
    _scope = TransactionHelper.CreateScope();
}

[TearDown]
public async Task TeardownTest()
{
    _scope.Dispose();
    _scope = null;
}

[Test]
public async Task Test11()
{
    var result = await OneTimeTestFixtureStartup.Client.GetAsync("api/values?dataName1=Name1&dataName2=Name2");
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
}
```

But it does NOT work (I can see modifications in DB after test run) for some reason and I cannot figure it out.

*Why? What am I missing?*

**Note:** both tests versions pass successfully.

Comment: please try removing `async` in your setup and teardown, you don't need it anyway. This could be the cause of the problem, need to confirm.

Comment: my guess is that even you use `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled`, but since the `_scope` is created and disposed in your `async` setup and teardown, it's created in `another thread context`, the scope inside your SUT does not participate in this context, so it has no effect

Comment: @KhanhTO but I need the `async` in `SetUp` at least because I'll need to put some data in DB before test run (the same applies to `OneTimeSetUp`/teardown and I've planned to have one more `TransactionScope` at that level as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to put data in DB in `[Setup]`, you may run this multiple times (one for each test), but since you have rollback already, this is unnessary. Maybe it makes more sense to put data only in `OneTimeSetUp`, in `OneTimeSetUp`, you don't need to rollback so you can use `async` there just fine

Comment: @KhanhTO Hmm, actually it does work with `void` SetUp/TearDown, just confirmed. I guess I can go with such config and then manually cleanup preloaded data in `OneTimeSetUp`/teardown../

Comment: @KhanhTO yeah, could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? It makes sence, I think I'll stick to your solution now, thanks!

Comment: The only thing that seems weird to me, i heard that .NET Core removed synchronization context, but `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` still works, my previous assumption about removing `async` also relies on the synchronization context, but i will check that later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution is removing `async` from `[SetUp]` and `[TearDown]`.

**Explanation:**

When `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` is used, the transaction scope should flow across thread continuations, but since `_scope` is created and disposed in the `async` setup and teardown, it's created and disposed in **other thread contexts** (not the same thread continuation). The `scope` inside the SUT does not participate in this context, so it has no effect

Comment: This worked fine in .NET Framework - only .NET Core appears to have problems with this. It may well be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the multiple threads.  `TransactionScope` uses thread local storage.  So you should be constructing, using and disposing of it all on one thread.  Quoting the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> You should also use the TransactionScope and DependentTransaction
>   class for applications that require the use of the same transaction
>   across multiple function calls or multiple thread calls.

So if you want to use `TransactionScope` in a thread-safe manner you need to use `DependentTransaction`.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.dependenttransaction?view=netframework-4.8) for an example on how to do so safely.

**Edit**

You can also use `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` when constructing the scope, which will prevent TLS and allow scope to flow through async/await calls.

Be aware the default is  `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Suppress`.

Comment: Hmm, but I already use `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` as can be seen from `CreateScope()`. Also I'm wondering whether `SingleThreadedAttribute` applies to `SetUp`/`TearDown` as according to [docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SingleThreaded-Attribute) it does for `OneTimeSetUp` and teardown...
The problem with `DependentTransaction` however is that I don't really want to 'pollute' my test methods and hence tried to put it in setup/teardown. Is there a way I can possibly rearchitecture tests to achieve the result without obviously cluttering the tests?