# Integration testing EF Core code with auto rollback transactions

Tags: entity-framework-core, integration-testing

We have integration tests on our ef core code in which we setup transactions that are always rolled back:

```
internal class AutoRollbackTransaction : IDisposable
{
    private TransactionScope _transaction = null;

    public AutoRollbackTransaction()
    {
        _transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_transaction != null) 
        {
            // intentionally not calling Complete();
            _transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

and then our unit tests look more or less like this:

```
        using (var transaction = new AutoRollbackTransaction())
        {
            // arrange, act, assert
        }
```

But i have started using EF Core Temporal tables now, and apparently those history records are only saved after the transaction completes. This really does make sense, but is there any way around this? I would like to keep using autorollback transactions, and would prefer not to do any manual cleanup.

Comment: I understand that running integration tests against an already existing database, usually the database you have in your DEV or QA environment is handy but it's not the best testing strategy to adopt. I would suggest to invest some time in creating your integration test database on the fly, populating it with the data you want to test and then destroy the db when tests are completed. Some refs:

- Test container for .net to deploy your sql server db: https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/
- Use Respawn: https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn

Answer (score 0):

> apparently those history records are only saved after the transaction completes

That's not true. History records are created immediately and are subject to regular transaction semantics.

Temporal tables in Entity Framework Core are implemented on top of [SQL Server system-versioned temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16). History records are generated by SQL Server itself.

For system-versioned temporal tables, SQL Server inserts a history record for each data modification performed as part of an `UPDATE` statement and for each data deletion performed as part of a `DELETE` statement. That happens [atomically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) with the modifications or deletion themselves. If an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement fails, history records insertions generated during its execution are rolled back. When a transaction of which an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement is part fails, history record insertions generated by such statements are rolled back as well.

> I would like to keep using autorollback transactions, and would prefer not to do any manual cleanup.

From a transactional perspective, there is nothing special about SQL Server system-versioned temporal tables. You can keep using autorollback transactions. No manual cleanup will be needed.

Answer (score -1):

When using EF Core Temporal tables and wanting to maintain automatic rollback transactions, managing the saving of historical records in temporary tables before your transactions are rolled back might be a challenging scenario. Depending on your TransactionScope, there could be a few ways to handle this situation:

- **Alter the usage of temporal tables:** Review the usage of temporal tables in accordance with your time dimension requirements. You might consider adopting a different approach for scenarios like saving historical records before the transaction completes.
- **Adopt an alternative approach:** Instead of automatic rollback transactions, consider using a method where you manually perform cleanup at the end of each test. This might involve a certain pattern for clearing temporary tables.
- **Limit the use of temporal tables:** Restrict the usage of temporal tables in your tests and enable the saving of historical records only in specific scenarios or conditions.

Each of these approaches can allow you to continue working with EF Core Temporal tables while maintaining automatic rollback transactions. However, it's crucial to evaluate whether each one fits your testing infrastructure and requirements.

Additionally, I suggest taking a look at this: [asp-net core integration tests rollback transaction after each tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711530/asp-net-core-integration-tests-rollback-transaction-after-each-tests?rq=2)